# Forward option is missing from the "message application" after it updated

Tags: applications, google-messages

My phone is MIUI Global 12.0.8, Android version 10 (QP1A.190711.020).

After the "messages" app updated, the "forward" option disappeared. As a result, I can no more forward messages. I tried to downgrade "messages", and this worked a short time, but then the app updated again, and there seems to be no way to prevent it to update.
What can I do?

Comment: There are lots of third party apps that can work as SMS app (reception and sending). For example messengers like Signal can also work as SMS app. Fell free to test such apps if they suite your needs.

Comment: The question is tagged with 'android-messages' which is specifically about [Google's Messages](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging) app. Is it the correct app?

Comment: @Andrew T. I'm not sure, that's the app that came with the phone as I bought it. But the app icone is the same as the link you provided, so I think it is the correct app.

Comment: If it is the same app, then have you tried long-pressing the message you want to forward? What options are shown on the top bar? Also, just in case, could you mention the installed app version?

Comment: Yes, of course. This was how the old version worked. Unfortunately, there is no more a "forward" option available. The version updated itself without my permission, but I'll have a look at it.

Comment: version messages.android_20221101_01_RC01

Comment: That's strange, I'm on `messages.android_20221115_01_RC00.phone.openbeta_dynamic` (Beta program; Pixel 3a, Android 12) and `phone_samsung_dynamic` (customized for Samsung devices; Galaxy M12, Android 12) but the forward option is still there. Have you checked for a few messages, not only one? Also, which version was the downgrade? Otherwise, any permissions blocked?

Comment: Yes, I've tried many messages. Regarding the downgrade version, sorry, too much for me. I've installed a better app.